# MySql Database Disconnectivity Issue with Grails

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, database-connection, mysql-error-1064

I am working with MySql connectivity with Grails Application. But unfortunately, application connection with mySql database is lost after the certain period of idle time (6-8 hours).

**I am getting the following Exception Continually:**

> ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No
>   operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly
>   closed due to underlying exception/error:
>
> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException MESSAGE: Communications link
>   failure due to underlying exception:
>
> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> java.net.SocketException MESSAGE: Software caused connection abort:
>   socket write error
>   Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>   due to underlying exception
>
> Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.

I am using the following properties in ***DataSource*** file of grails   application:

```
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{db_name}"

    properties {
        jmxEnabled = true
        initialSize = 5
        maxActive = 50
        minIdle = 5
        maxIdle = 25
        maxWait = 10000
        maxAge = 10 * 60000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
        validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
        validationQueryTimeout = 3
        validationInterval = 15000
        testOnBorrow = true
        testWhileIdle = true
        testOnReturn = false
        jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
        defaultTransactionIsolation = Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    }
```

**Note:** I Read in Web that `autoReconnect=true` doesn't work.

Please guide me If I am missing any attribute to mention in properties while making the connection with mySql.

Comment: Actually, have you tried `autoReconnect=true` or just assume it won't work?

Comment: lot of articles show that It doesn't work as it throws exception. Now, added it with url to see what actually happen.

Comment: Just tried with `autoReconnect=true` and this also didn't work.

Comment: Did you get the same stacktrace or other exception? Which version of MySQL are you using?  Which version of MySQL plugin for Grails are you using? Which version of Grails are you using? Did you check your MySQL logs?